# Increase float precision

Tags: python

I am developing a machine learning based algorithm on python. The main thing, that I need to calculate to solve this problem is probabilities. This way I have the following code:

```
class_ans = class_probability[current_class] * lambdas[current_class]
for word in appears_words:
   if word in message:
      class_ans *= words_probability[(word, current_class)]
   else:
      class_ans *= (1 - words_probability[(word, current_class)])
 
   ans.append(class_ans)
   ans[current_class] /= summ
```

It works, but in case the dataset is too big or **lambdas** value is too small, I ran out of my float precision.

I've tryed to research an other algorithm of calculating my answer's value, multimplying and dividing on some random consts different variables to make them not to overflow. Despite this, nothing helped.

This way, I would like to ask, is there any ways to increase my float precision in python?

Thanks!

Comment: [bigfloat](https://pypi.org/project/bigfloat/)

Comment: You can’t simply increase float precision. The usual solution here is to transform the domain of calculation into log space. That is, log all individual values and use addition instead of multiplication to calculate conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. When using serious scientific computation where precision is key (and speed is not), consider the following two options:

1. Instead of using `float`, switch your datatype to `decimal.Decimal` and set your desired precision.
2. For a more battle-hardened thorough implementation, switch to `gmpy2.mpfr` as your data type.

However, if your entire computation (or at least the problematic part) involves the multiplication of factors, you can often bypass the need for the above by working in log-space as Konrad Rudolph suggests in the comments:

```
a * b * c * d * ... = exp(log(a) + log(b) + log(c) + log(d) + ...)
```